# Changes not visible on table data

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, transactions, submitchanges

I would like to perform a transaction by using LINQ and SQL Server CE.

The `SubmitChanges` method seems to work fine. But if I look in the data table the changes are not applied.

My code:

```
var query = (from s in this.tblRequirements
where s.abbrevation == "rml"
select new {s}).First();

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("First: " + query.s.abbrevation);

query.s.abbrevation = "rmlas";

try
{ 
    this.rdb.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (ChangeConflictException e)
{ 
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); 
}

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Second: " + query.s.abbrevation);

query = (from s in this.tblRequirements
         where s.requirementID == 4
         select new { s }).First();

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Third: " + query.s.abbrevation);
```

Message output:

```
First = "rml"
Second = "rmlas"
Third = "rmlas"
```

My table:

```
[requirementID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[credentialID]  INT           DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
[softwareName]  NCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
[abbrevation]   NCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
[uri]           NVARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
[version]       NCHAR(15)     DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
[installPath]   TEXT          DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
[samedir]       BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[subPathID]     INT           NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([requirementID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_RequirementsAnnotation_Credentials] 
     FOREIGN KEY ([credentialID]) 
     REFERENCES [dbo].[Credential] ([credentialID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_RequirementsAnnotation_SubPath] 
     FOREIGN KEY ([subPathID]) 
     REFERENCES [dbo].[SubPath] ([subPathID])
```

The console output:

```
> SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[requirementID], [t0].[credentialID],
> [t0].[softwareName], [t0].[abbrevation], [t0].[uri], [t0].[version],
> [t0].[installPath], [t0].[samedir], [t0].[subPathID] FROM
> [dbo].[RequirementsAnnotation] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[abbrevation] = @p0
> -- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [rml]
> -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) 
> Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.33440
> 
> UPDATE [dbo].[RequirementsAnnotation] SET [abbrevation] = @p7 WHERE
> ([requirementID] = @p0) AND ([credentialID] = @p1) AND ([softwareName]
> = @p2) AND ([abbrevation] = @p3) AND ([uri] = @p4) AND ([version] = @p5)
> AND ([installPath] IS NULL) AND (NOT ([samedir] = 1)) AND
> ([subPathID] = @p6)
> -- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [4]
> -- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
> -- @p2: Input NChar (Size = 30; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [repeats    ]
> -- @p3: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [rml       ]
> -- @p4: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [xyz]
> -- @p5: Input NChar (Size = 15; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [20140131       ]
> -- @p6: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [2]
> -- @p7: Input NChar (Size = 10; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [rmlas]
> -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel
```

This result appears after each call.

Comment: Which Database you check and not saw change in it ? Database that located in debug folder? or in main folder in your solution?

Comment: The database is RequirementsAnnotation and is located in DebugFolder under ./Databases (mdf, dbml)

Comment: Are you using TransactionScope (without calling complete) anywhere in your program? Failing that, I would suspect that either you are looking at the wrong database, or your database is getting overwritten (possibly when you build your project).

Answer (score 0):

I using this code for update and you can help from it. it work well for me. if its not work for you, you have other wrong and not in that code you send.

```
 using (phoneDBContext db1 = new phoneDBContext())
                {
                    IQueryable<Project> cityQuery = from c in db1.Projects
                                                    where c.Id == 56
                                                    select c;
                    Project p = cityQuery.FirstOrDefault();
                    p.Project_name = "rmlas";
                    db1.SubmitChanges();
                }
```

Comment: What are you changed?

Comment: I change two thing. this.tblRequirements  to rdb.tblRequirements, and this.rdb.SubmitChanges(); to rdb.SubmitChanges();.  . its work now ?

Comment: unfortunately not. After call, the program keeps the new data. But after a recall, the data are lost.

Comment: Just change my code as you want using for your program. and tell me result.